# how to create zoomable image slider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i needs zoomable image slider with cached network image something like this:
[image: user can double toch on it and zoom and backzoom]

user can zoom on it and back

Comment: https://medium.com/@ms.thitsarnyanlynn/flutter-how-to-make-image-carousel-with-zoomable-image-8a72c673f806

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin from Flutter to create the slider "Carousel Slider"
https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

and Include photos in Photo view widget

```
PhotoView(
          imageProvider: AssetImage(photos),
          backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
        ),
```